# Program can not be run as Java Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet, awt

I wrote a simple program that couldn't be run as a Java Applet. When I tried to run the program, a frame did pop up and and asked which program to be run. I clicked the program I wrote, which is shown below. Surprisingly, Eclipse would run other programs in the same default package. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Here is one program from The Art and Science of Java Chapter 6 Exercise 3:

### ApproxPIValue

```
import acm.util.*;

public class ApproxPIValue {

public void run() {
    int total = 0; //This variable counts the amount of time x^2 + y^2 < 1.//
    for (int a = 0; a < 10000; a++) { 
        double x = rgen.nextDouble(-1.0, 1.0);
        double y = rgen.nextDouble(-1.0, 1.0);
        if (Math.sqrt(x) + Math.sqrt(y) < 1) { //x^2 + y^2 < 1 means that     this pair number will fall into the circle with radius of 1 centered in the middle     of the coordinates.  
            total++;
        }
        double approxPIValue = total / 10000 * 4; //total / 100000 is the approximate ratio of the area of the circle over the area of the square. The approximate ratio would be close to PI/4 if x and y are randomly chosen. So total / 10000 * 4 will give the approximate PI.//
        System.out.print(approxPIValue);
    }
}

/* set RandomGenerator as an instance variable. */
private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
}
```

I also want to pose another program that doesn't work either.

### CoinFace

```
import acm.util.*;

/**
 * This class decides the face of a coin. 
 * 1 and 2 represent correspondingly Heads and Tails.
 * Clients can get the "face" of the coin by calling getState() method.
 */

public class CoinFace {

public CoinFace() {
    state = rgen.nextInt(1, 2);
}


/* private instance variable.  */
private int state;

public int getState() {
    return state;
}

/* declare RandomGenerator as an instance variable. */
private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
}
```

### ConsecutiveHeads

```
public class ConsecutiveHeads extends CoinFace{
public void run () {
    while (true) {
        int totalFlip = 0;
        int consecutiveHeads = 0; //the time of getting consecutive Heads when flipping a coin.//
        CoinFace a = new CoinFace();
        if (a.getState() == 1) {
            System.out.print("Heads");
            totalFlip++;
            consecutiveHeads++;
        } else if (consecutiveHeads == 3) {
            System.out.print("It took " + totalFlip + " to get 3 consecutive heads." );
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Tails");
            consecutiveHeads = 0;
            totalFlip++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Since I couldn't run the program, I don't know how the programs would turn out. Thanks in advance for any solution and advice on improving the programs!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but applets are embedded in html and must extend Applet class?

Comment: @csmckelvey, I am not sure. Because when i check other programs, I right click on them and choose "Run As," other programs will have "run as Java Applet," or "run on server." The programs that don't work don't show the option for "run as Java Applet."

Comment: @csmckelvey *"applets are embedded in html"* Not always.  An applet can be launched free floating using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). *"and must extend Applet class?"*  Either that or `JApplet` (which itself extends `Applet`).

Comment: @csmckelvey,do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of warning in your console.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the clarification. Never ran an applet free floating before.

Comment: @VinayakPingale,the amazing thing is I didn't get any kind of warning.

Comment: Well, first things first, extend either `Applet` or `JApplet` class.

Comment: @csmckelvey  *"Never ran an applet free floating before."*  To be honest, neither have I.  ;)  The fact is, an applet launched that way ends up in the AppletViewer, which I think is so ugly it is only for developers to see.  I *have* made various ***Hybrid application/applets***, but the route to go in that case is to make the GUI in a `JPanel`, then put the panel in either a `JApplet` or `JFrame` as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACM `JApplet` is apparently called a [`Program`](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts//jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/Program.html).  An app. must extend `Program` if it is to be embedded in a web page.

But why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should *stop* teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: How not to code an applet? I just want to open the program and see if it works.

Comment: *"How not to code an applet?"*  I could write a book on that.  If you asked a separate question on it, it would be closed as 'too broad'.  But for a tip:  I distilled my years of experience with applets into the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) here at SO.  It contains some great links to tutorials and other information you are going to need.  But when it comes to applets, there is no 'just' about it.  Did you actually *read* the blog article to which I linked?  If not, start there.